# wget -O for non-existing save path?

Tags: linux, wget

I can't `wget` while there is no path already to save. I mean, `wget` doens't work for the non-existing save paths. For e.g:

```
wget -O /path/to/image/new_image.jpg http://www.example.com/old_image.jpg
```

If `/path/to/image/` is not previously existed, it always returns:

```
No such file or directory
```

How can i make it work to automatically create the path and save?

Comment: don't think there is an option. you have to create them before firing wget.

Comment: So i can't manage it programmatically for the whole complete work? :(

Comment: Is it possible this is just a permissions issue? It seems that wget creates new directories just fine by default.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try `curl`

```
curl http://www.site.org/image.jpg --create-dirs -o /path/to/save/images.jpg
```

Comment: @4lvin `curl` is a more powerful tool.

Comment: Woww! ya.. Agree now. Coz when i run batch jobs, `wget` got `spawn` error.. but `curl` works very well!!

Comment: Note the difference in capitalization of `-O` versus `-o`.

Comment: note that this won't follow redirects without the `-L` flag. `curl` is great for interactive use, but I prefer `wget` for unattended use

Answer (score 7):

```
mkdir -p /path/i/want && wget -O /path/i/want/image.jpg http://www.com/image.jpg
```

Comment: Woah it works buddy. But so, it means.. it can't be done by only `wget`. Rite? :T I'm surprising how come `wget` is that weak :(

Comment: take a look at my answer then you can do it with wget only!

Comment: it needs to run `mkdir` command together. Not only one `wget` command. But whatever, it works.

Comment: no it dosnt, read my answer and understand it :P the first one is a 1liner and the second is pure wget.

Comment: The problem with this is that it creates an empty directory if wget wasn't able to fetch the file.

Comment: Actually, under Windows at least, wget 1.8.2 creates a zero-length file if it can't fetch the page -- that seems like a bug, to me.

Answer (score 7):

To download a file with wget, into a **new directory**, use `--directory-prefix` **without** `-O`:

```
wget --directory-prefix=/new/directory/ http://www.example.com/old_image.jpg
```

Using `-O new_file` in conjunction with `--directory-prefix`, **will not create the new directory** structure, and will save the new file in the current directory. 
It may even fail with "*No such file or directory*" error, if you specify `-O /new/directory/new_file`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create folder if it doesn't exists with this command:
`wget -N http://www.example.com/old_image.jpg -P /path/to/image`

Comment: Is this link suppose to show anything: http://www.example.com/old_image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

wget is only getting a file NOT creating the directory structure for you (mkdir -p /path/to/image/), you have to do this by urself:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/image/ && wget -O /path/to/image/new_image.jpg http://www.example.com/old_image.jpg
```

You can tell wget to create the directory (so you dont have to use mkdir) with the parameter `--force-directories`

alltogether this would be

```
wget --force-directories -O /path/to/image/new_image.jpg http://www.example.com/old_image.jpg
```

Comment: The second part of your answer appears to be incorrect, as --force-directories appears to only force the creation of directories related to the hierarchy of the source site / location. See http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory-Options.html

Comment: sorry but this answer is wrong as noted by BSchlinker...retract your votes!

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot, I finally found **a way to use `wget` to download for non-existing path**.

```
wget -q --show-progress -c -nc -r -nH -i "$1"

=====
Clarification

-q
--quiet --show-progress
  Kill annoying output but keep the progress-bar

-c
--continue
  Resume download if the connection lost

-nc
--no-clobber
  Overwriting file if exists

-r
--recursive
  Download in recursive mode (What topic creator asked for!)

-nH
--no-host-directories
  Tell wget do not use the domain as a directory (for e.g: https://example.com/what/you/need
   - without this option, it will download to "example.com/what/you/need")

-i
--input-file
  File with URLs need to be download (in case you want to download a lot of URLs,
   otherwise just remove this option)
```

Happy wget-ing!

Comment: This discards the paths rather than creating them.

Comment: @GarethDavidson What you means with discard the path? When I used the command it really create non-exists paths for me from a list (`$1`)

Comment: I mean usually if you `wget https://some.site/dir/file.txt` then you'll get `./dir/file.txt`. I think with `-i input.txt` that contains `https://some.site/dir/file.txt` you'll get `./file.txt`. Am I wrong? I should check

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is how to create the output directory in combination with the `-O` flag.

Comment: He can't use `-O`, because that is called `-r` in wget. `-nH` to ignore `example.com`. In short, you can't use `-O` with `wget`, must be a combination of parameters.